# How to use JQuery DatePicker or angularJS to display days of the week alone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on a project that needs me to do three things depending on the options chosen. The options in a dropdown are *Daily*, *Weekly*, *Monthly*, and *Yearly*.

> If *Weekly* is chosen, I just need the **days** of the week to be displayed as buttons.
>
> If *Monthly* is chosen, I just need the **dates** (1-31) to be displayed as buttons.
>
> If *Yearly* is chosen, I just need the **months** of the year to be displayed as buttons.

Can I use *options* in datepicker or angularJS (I'm still learning angularJS) to get this to work?

Note that, once I choose the option from the dropdown, I will prefer the buttons to populate in the div I specify (meaning, I won't be clicking on an input box to display a calendar).

If there is an alternative to datepicker or calendarUI, I would be willing to try that as well. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance for all the suggestions.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Plnkr or jsfiddle would have been helpful to answer your question.

Comment: javaCity - I have just the plain JS similar to one shown below by lpg. I'm wondering if there is an alternative to that using JQuery datepicker. I will try to get something up on jsfiddle today.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like this ([Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9SjpG/)):

```
var days = ['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'];

function getContent(dateScope)
{
    var ret = "";
    switch(dateScope) {
        case "w": for(i in days)
            ret += "<button>"+days[i]+"</button>";
            break;
        case "m": for(i=1;i<=31;i++)
            ret += "<button>"+i+"</button>";
            break;
        case "y": for(i=1;i<=12;i++)
            ret += "<button>"+i+"</button>";
            break;
    }
    return ret;
}

$("#dateScope").change(function(){
    $("#buttonsDiv").html(getContent($(this).val()));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I had thought of this as well. That was my last option if there wasn't a library that already did that. Just curious to see if there was one :)