# How to make jquery datepicker days of week?

Tags: jquery

I want jquery datepicker in days of week take to divs. How to make jquery datepicker days of week.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/P5thZfE]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JQuery DatePicker or angularJS to display days of the week alone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048084/how-to-use-jquery-datepicker-or-angularjs-to-display-days-of-the-week-alone)

Comment: what you try before, please give the code which you tried